# Can't get apache working after installing nginx & hhvm

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, fastcgi, hhvm

I had Apache2 running on my local ubuntu machine and I installed nginx & hhvm on my local for debugging purposes by following [this tutorial](https://richardtape.com/2015/03/07/from-php-to-hhvm/).

I would now like to switch back to Apache2 as I had it before, previously I had both Apache & NGINX with PHP5-FPM running and I could switch between them by running:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when I try this I get the below error when I try to access my Magento app

```
/var/www/app/Mage.php was not found
```

I can however see the default Ubuntu Apache page when I go to http://localhost/

I tried running

```
~:$ sudo service nginx stop
~:$ sudo service hhvm stop
~:$ sudo service apache2 restart 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                               [ OK ] 
~:$ sudo service php5-fpm restart 
stop: Unknown instance: 
php5-fpm start/running, process 12258
~:$ sudo service php5-fpm restart 
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 12281
```

And now I get a 503 service unavailable error when I try to access my Magento app in the browser.  I know in Magento this error can be caused by a maintenance.flag file in the Magento root directory but this is not the case here.

My Apache error log says:

```
[Sat Jun 27 11:11:07.902430 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 12223] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Sat Jun 27 11:11:07.902490 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12223] [client 127.0.0.1:39494] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1[Sat Jun 27 11:11:07.902430 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 12223] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Sat Jun 27 11:11:07.902490 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12223] [client 127.0.0.1:39494] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

When I installed HHVM I ran it's install_fastcgi.sh script.  Could that be what is causing the issue.

Any idea on how I can switch between NGINX to Apache and not use HHVM on my local.

---

### UPDATE

I tried @mboehn solution below and now I'm getting the original error in the browser when I navigate to my Magento apps URL

[image]

This should be looking in `/var/www/magento/app/` for `Mage.php`.  And `index.php` is in `/var/www/magento/`.  The start of index.php is:

```
/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

But this is how Magento apps normally run and I made no changes here.  Just installed HHVM and stopped it to revert back to my previous Apache config.

There is nothing in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

In I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
ServerName http://dev.magento.local
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory /var/www/magento>
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### 2nd Update

Ok so there was a index.php in the `/var/www/` path that was throwing me off, it was just a copy of something I had been working on ages ago that hadn't caused a problem before.

After removing it I get the bellow message in my browser.

*File not found.*

And now in my apache error log it says
`[Sat Jun 27 12:33:58.382270 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16003] [client 127.0.0.1:40412] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'`

Comment: Are you sure that the path `/var/www/app/` isn't set somewhere in for example `index.php`? I believe you should have seen an error in Apache's error.log if it were Apache that returned a 404 (file not found) error.

Comment: @mboehn it's not a 404 error just a message in the browser.  I updated my question with more details.  The Magento App is the same as it has always been and it works with HHVM.  I need to swicth back to apache as an important product import plugin for Magento does not work with HHVM.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but index.php believes it's being run from /var/www, and that probably means that it is. I would have checked that there isn't a copy or link of index.php in /var/www, and that my HTTP request is actually hitting the Apache configuration that I want it to (and not ie. the default one pointing to /var/www). If you request http://dev.magento.local/unknownXYZ you should see the path Apache looks for in error.log

Comment: @mboehn, that was it had a stray index.php file in `/var/www/`.  No I have a message in my error log `[Sat Jun 27 12:33:58.382270 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16003] [client 127.0.0.1:40412] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'`

Comment: I'm guessing you have an Apache configuration file point to /var/www as the DocumentRoot. The Apache configuration you've pasted, did you replace the default configuration (`/etc/apache/sites-available/default`) with it, or did you make another file (now in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/`)? You might need to disable the `default`-site configuration.

Comment: @mboehn, no my Apache conf file points to /var/www/magento and the default Apache conf file is disabled.  Apache was working fine until I installed and removed HHVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it :)**

When I installed HHVM I ran the below shell script which set HHVM and changed some configurations.

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh
```

I'm not sure exactly what this did but I'm almost certain it is what caused the issue as when I ran the below uninstall script which also comes with HHVM it fixed everything and now Apache works also.

```
$ sudo /usr/share/hhvm/uninstall_fastcgi.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have php5-fpm listening on a unix socket (like `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, while Apache tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000.

Check the `listen`-directive in your php5-fpm configuration (I'm guessing `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`). And then either configure Apache to use the unix socket or reconfigure both php5-fpm and nginx to use network sockets (a port)

- Make php5-fpm use port 9000:

  - In `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, replace `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` with `listen = 127.0.0.1`
- Apache already uses port 9000
- Make ngnix use port 9000:

  - In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (this is the default file, you might be using another file in the same directory), replace `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` with `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: in www.conf I have `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.  I want to swicth back to apache, should I configure this to use a port? How?  Sorry I'm new to server config.

Comment: why would installing hhvm have changed it.

Comment: I've explained more in my answer now. Exactly why installing hhvm changed this I'm not sure of, but I don't know what the script `install_fastcgi.sh` does. It seems that having php5-fpm use unix sockets is  the default these days.

Comment: thanks I tried that but it gave me the original error I was getting before.  I updated my question.